# Struts 2 json result for List of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, json, regex, struts2

I have an `ArrayList` of arrays `ArrayList<[obj1,obj2]>`. Here `obj1` and `obj2` are different Java entities and this list is returned by a HQL query.

How to loop through this list in `struts.xml` file to send this as JSON result?

I tried below combination but with no luck:

1. `^itemList\[\d+\]\.^\[\0+\].id` --> id is a property of entity
2. `^itemList\[\d+\]\.\0\.id`
3. `^itemList\[\d+\]\.co.id` --> co = entity alias in hql
4. `^itemList\[\d+\]\[0].id`
5. `^itemList\[\d+\]\.\[\0+\].id`
6. `^itemList\[\d+\]\.[0].id`

### edit:

I used it in `struts.xml` as follows:

```xml
<action name="list-view-op-cost-management_cons"  class="com.eves.aixis.s2.action.billing.ConsignmentBillingGridAction" method="listViewOperationalCostForManagement">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
                <param name="includeProperties">
                    viewType,
                    searchType,
                    searchValue,
                    service,
                    page,
                    total,
                    records,
                    ^itemList\[\d+\]\.^\[\0+\].id,
                    reqaction_,
                    actionResult,
                    ^errorList\[\d+\]
                    
                </param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Edit:

```
Obj1 = Consignment(Bussiness entity)
```

with fileds:

```
private Integer id;
    private String consignmentNo;
    private Customer sender;
    private Contact senderContact;
    private Pickup pickupRef;
    private Receiver receiver;
    private List<Invoice> invoiceList;
    private ConsignmentStatus consignmentStatus;
    private Boolean invoiceToReiver;
    private String deliveryInstruction;
    private String customerReference;
    private List<PackageDescription> packageDescription;// actual package info
    private List<PackageDescription> custPackage;//use in ecp (external customer portal) and use in inquiry given customer package details
    private List<PackageDescription> revProtPackages;//revenue protection packages
    
    private Receiver deliveryAddress;
    private List<ConsignmentTrack> connoteTrack;
    private ProductType productType;
    private List<Commodity> commodities;
    private PreBriefDeskVerify briefDeskVerify;
```

and

```
obj2 = SalesOrder(Bussiness entity)
```

with fileds:

```
private Long id;
    private SalesOrderType salesItemType;
    
    private Consignment salesItem;  
                                    
    private MasterAirwayBill mawb; 
    private Pickup pickupSI;
    private Delivery deliverySI;

    
    private WHSalesItem whSalesItem;
    
    
    private Job job;
    private SCMBillingState billingState;
    
    
    private Tariff tariff; 

    private Tariff tariffForPrinciples; 
   

    private List<SalesOrderLineItem> salesOrderItemList;
    private String remarks;
    private SalesOrderStatus salesOrderStatus;
```

Comment: How did you use it in `struts.xml`?

Comment: @RomanC I edited the question with struts.xml code

Answer (score 0):

The param `includeProperties` contains a list of regexes, that you use to match properties of the serializable to JSON object. This regex expression should match your property name, try it

```
^itemList.*$
```

If you want only `id` property, then you can try

```
^itemList.*\.id$
```

Comment: <br/> But the thing is two objects obj1 and obj2 has same properties(id ), so that I need to get the json result clearly for two objects, but I will try with this

Comment: You should be more specific with your requirements, what is the actual type of `obj2`?

Comment: Those are business Objects of the related domain; I will edit the Question with those info.

Comment: I tried with following ;                                                                       ^itemList\[\d+\].*\.id$,
\[\d+\]\.id$,                                                                                                 but didn't give the result. It only gives this json; {"actionResult":"SUCCESS","errorList":[],"page":1,"records":100,"reqaction_":null,"searchType":"conNo","searchValue":"241622668","service":"IE","total":10}

Comment: This is your expression and it doesn't work, I don't know who are you following.

Comment: The error is ok, it means that you *can* access `itemList`'s properties.

Comment: Yes with that I was able to get an empty array of arrays in json String. That means I can access the collection.

Comment: The error from this question is using wrong regex to access the action properties. It was not accessible and no exception was thrown. When you use regexes from this answer the property became accessible, the fact that it throws exception, I guess it's lazy loading problem and it should be asked in a separate page. Also to not duplicate my answers I recommend you to search SO for similar question that already has an answer. I have provided answers to this problem several times.